# Git: Change master branch?

Tags: git

Say I have these  git branches:

```
master
branchone
```

I want to do this, keeping all history intact:

```
master -> oldmaster
branchone -> master
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `git branch -m`.

```
git branch -m master tmpbranch
git branch -m branchone master
git branch -m tmpbranch branchone
```